# Reading and writing to XML file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.forms shared project, I would like to write and read from a XML file which has to reside locally on each of the platform (android, iOS and windows).

I referred to this: [Working with files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/), but I seem to be getting error :

```
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'SharedPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

at line: `var assembly = typeof(SharedPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;`

As I am new to Xamarin.forms I would also like to know where the files has to be placed for each of the platform project.

Comment: Just as a heads up, I found Xamarin.Forms very appealing at first but eventually had to abandon it due to serious performance issues and lack of UI control.

Comment: I don't know if this will make a difference but if I remember correctly changing 'typeof(SharedPage)' to 'typeof(this)' worked for me.

Comment: @OwenJames doesn't seem to work for me :-(

Comment: If you pop your solution in a zip file I will take a look if you want?  It will be something simple.  My contact details are on my profile.

Comment: Thats very nice of you. :-) I will mail you source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your are referencing the namespace as `Test151.XML.WinPhone`, however the real namespace you should be referring to is `Test151.WinPhone.XML`, as your `WinPhone` project has an assembly root of `Test151.WinPhone`.

So your have to change this within your TryFile.cs:-

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
            //var resourcePrefix = "Test151.XML.WinPhone.";
            var resourcePrefix = "Test151.WinPhone.XML.";
#endif
```

Your also trying to get resource from the XML folder, of which you have not set the file as an `EmbeddedResource`, so you need to do that also.

Further, your attempting to use the assembly of `Xamarin.Forms` to try and load the resource from, so where-as you had this:-

```
var assembly = typeof(ContentPage).GetType().Assembly;
```

You need to change it to something along the lines of this:-  (due to it being a `SharedProject` it will give you the correct assembly where to load the resource from.

```
    var assembly = typeof(TryFile).Assembly;
```

One last thing, your mentioning you want to read and write from an XML file.  This code part that you've implemented from the 'Working with files' page, you mentioned, will not help you as you are attempting to load an embedded resource, of which you can't write back, unless your aim is to write this to the file system afterwards?

Its the second half of the document you need to really be focusing on, if your aim is to accomplish reading and writing to an file in local storage.

Comment: Hi @pete Could you please help me out getting the correct directory for PCL project. `var assembly = typeof(TryFile).Assembly;` does not work for PCL project

Comment: I had to move to PCL project as client requested to go for it.

Comment: OMG! Why nobody ever explains this type? I can't find an explanation for it. Did you fix it for PCL?

Comment: Remember to add `using System.Reflection;` and then you just use `var assembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;`